# What is a component joomla

Tags: joomla

I know what a continuous joomla components, I find that for each component (example com_users) consists of three standard folder (Models, Views, Controllers) and the controller class for the controller of controllers controlos file

my question is: what are the standard folders + files from a joomla component??

why there are several folders in the views folder of a joomla component is that for each file in the folder represents viewrs action on this page

Comment: folders related to different views

Answer (score 0):

below is the joomla component folder structure.

### main folder

site
admin

### files

### in - site folder

componentname.php
controller.php

### in site folder - views folder

### in views folder - view name folder

view.html.php

### in view name folder - tmpl folder

default.php

---

### in site folder - models folder

models.php

---

### in site folder - controllers folder

controllername.php

referance below link

http://docs.joomla.org/File_Structure_and_Naming_Conventions